# Bluetooth re-connecting on reboot of nexdock

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I have a nexdock laptop. I have to connect bluetooth (pair) each time I bootup Raspbian.

I followed the directions to add a command line in the `crontab -e` menu. Still have to pair the nexdock. Anyone know what I could be doing wrong? this is what I type:

```
@reboot echo connect (insert my Mac Address) | bluetoothctl
```